References on Starobinsky inflation and quadratic gravity in cosmology
I'm learning about inflation and would like to read more about Starobinsky inflation and the predictions of quadratic gravity (i.e., Starobinsky plus Weyl squared) to inflationary cosmology. An ideal reference would not assume much previous knowledge about inflation, but as long as a standard cosmology textbook (e.g. Baumann, Weinberg, etc) is a sufficient background I guess I can work around that.

I can recommend the original paper of Starobinsky: “A New Type of Isotropic Cosmological Models Without
Singularity,” Phys. Lett. B 91 (1980) 99–102.
If you are interested about its predictions on black holes, I can recommend this other paper: R. Campos Delgado, S. V. Ketov, “Schwarzschild-type black holes in
Starobinsky-Bel-Robinson gravity,” Phys. Lett. B 838 (2023) 137690.
